# Python: I need to parse a binary file in python with mixture of encoded data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I have a file which contains encoded data in Latin - 1 coded and binary coded depending upon the position of the byte.
I want to create a parser that can read that binary data, analyze it and filter the unwanted data.
Issue: I am not able to view the binary file's actual format so that I can analyze the pattern and remove the unnecessary data.
I am not able to handle this issue.
I have tried using bytearray but it fails because it requires encoding.And reading byte by byte also results is false data.

```
with open("FOA", "rb") as f:  
  with open("FA", "w") as d:  
    byte = f.read(1)  
    while byte != "":  
        # Do stuff with byte.  
        print(byte)  
        d.write(str(byte))  
        byte = f.read(1)
```

I have not used bcoz i wanted to see the result.But i think its not giving correct output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know which byte positions are Latin-1 strings and which are binary data? If so, it's pretty easy.

Comment: If not, there's really no firm rules that can tell you that some bytes are Latin-1 text vs. binary data. There are some good heuristics (NUL bytes and unmapped/private-use characters are probably binary, control characters except `\n` and maybe `\r` and `\t` are pretty likely to be binary, strings of 4 or more printable characters are more likely to be text than shorter ones, strings of letters are more likely to be text than strings of symbols, etc.), but how good those heuristics are depends heavily on exactly what kind of data you have. Try running `strings` on it and see how close it is.